# PyQT saving Items (The whole Method) inside GraphicsView and Loading them?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

Here a shotscreen that resumes everything

[image]

I have a Graphic Sceen within a GraphicView .

In My GUI I have a button that creates a movable and selectable items that need to be positioned .

I want to be able to save the instances created with their position , color and also I have to add a piece of code from other software (let's say a variable created with each instance) that also required to be saved as well with each instance  .

So a need to save the methods created each time I press the button create and load them back .
I don't have how to do it ? 
The show button (yellow in the picture) is able to display each item with their respective position . That's all I got !

Minal Code as requested : (I can copy past the whole code if you want but they are not related to the question )

class DesignerUI(QtWidgets.QDialog):

```
def __init__(self, parent=maya_main_window()):
    super(DesignerUI, self).__init__(parent) 

    self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
    self.scene.setParent(self.view)
                #Show me the datails about the select item
def showme(self):
    st = self.scene.selectedItems()
    print(st)

                    #Button to Create Items 
def do_it(self):
    c3 = QtGui.QColor(10, 20, 200, 127)                #Color 
    p3 = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)) # Border 
    el2 = self.scene.addEllipse(320,245,100,50, p3, c3)
    el2.setFlags(el2.ItemIsMovable | el2.ItemIsSelectable | el2.ItemIsFocusable )

    #Other Functionalities from Other software

    self.update()  

def saveFile(self):
    pass


def loadFile(self):
    pass
```

Comment: It's good practice to post some code so that we can help you, you can edit the question and put formatted code so that it looks nice for everyone and everybody can copy it and try. Even better is a minimal working example that exhibit what you are trying to do and where you get stuck!

Comment: please show your code([mre]) as text